# HTML Save button, with checkbox persisted state

Tags: html

assume I'm using HTML for something it's not really meant for and humor me.

I have the following code example which works but is there a way to persist the checkbox states into the downloaded HTML?
or has anyone come across something that could do this?

Many thanks,

```
<body>

<h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>

<a href ="#" id="donwload-link" onClick="myFunction()">download html content</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  download(content, "index", "html")

}
function download(content, fileName, fileType) {
  var link = document.getElementById("donwload-link");
  var file = new Blob([content], {type: fileType});
  var donwloadFile = fileName + "." + fileType;
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  link.download = donwloadFile
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add "checked" to the selected checkbox before the user download it.

Comment: If you need to save the changed state of the checkbox, then use `localStorage`.